# open-vm-tools copy/paste - vmtoolsd vmusr not running

Tags: ubuntu, copy-paste, vmware-workstation

im running kubuntu 23 and have installed open-vm-tools and open-vm-tools-desktop and things work fine for the most part however the copy/paste feature isnt working. after a lot of digging i found that if i run `vmtoolsd -n vmusr` that the copy/paste functionality works.

from the service logs it seems like everything is starting/running fine but for some reason this wont work unless i manually run it. It seems like im missing some configuration to tell it to auto run, but i've been unable to figure it out.

in the `/etc/vmware-tools/tools.conf` i have

```
isolation.tools.copy.disable = "FALSE"
isolation.tools.paste.disable = "FALSE"
```

which was there by default and from what i can tell says to enable that feature, and i assume should start the service.

I saw some suggestions to add the following, but that had no impact

```
[guestinfo]
procs.guestMode = "FALSE"

[vmtoolsd]
username = jrich523
```

most of the recommendations were to reinstall/reboot or something basic like that, which i've tried many times with no luck.

any idea what i might be missing?